# Powershell Variable format

Tags: variables, powershell

I am trying to call a variable and use it as an -forwardingsmtpaddress in a command. Why can I type the email address in the command, it works.  The variable is a string value. Is the header messing it up?

The variable and output is:

```
  $EmailAddress

  Emailaddress
 ----------------
 user@domain.com 


 C:\Windows\system32> Set-Mailbox -identity $loginid -ForwardingSmtpAddress "$emailaddress"

 emailaddress                                                                                                                                 

 ------------                                                                                                                                 

 user@domain.com                                                                                                                  

 ' isn't a valid SMTP address. Property Name: ForwardingSmtpAddress
 At C:\Users\xxx\AppData\Local\Temp\tmp_eaj0q1mh.s1i\tmp_eaj0q1mh.s1i.psm1:51509 char:9
 +         $steppablePipeline.End()
 +         ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
 + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (0:Int32) [Set-Mailbox], DataValidationException
 + FullyQualifiedErrorId : BDB22E0A,Microsoft.Exchange.Management.RecipientTasks.SetMailbox
 + PSComputerName        : mail01
```

Comment: Your variable is probably a PSObject rather than a string. Type `$EmailAddress.GetType()` to see its type.

Comment: @Bill_Stewart pegged it - if it were a string it wouldn't have the Emailaddress header when you get the value.

Comment: I piped it to get-member and see typename.system.string. But gettype shows name string and basetype as system.object. I can't call it when I type $emailaddres.emailaddress it is not listed as an option to choose and comes up blank.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like $emailaddress is an object with a property of emailaddress.

Try:

```
Set-Mailbox -identity $loginid -ForwardingSmtpAddress $emailaddress.emailaddress
```

Edit: if the variable really is a string then yes, that header is definitely going to mess it up.

Comment: I had piped it to out-string when messing with it. Your solution worked except for the -forwardingsmtpaddress vs -forwardingaddress. I wanted the forwardingaddress so i can see it in the GUI.